# Closed vector space, open versus closed set

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, definition

I read from [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html) that; a **vector space** $V$ is a **set** that is *closed* under finite vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Here my understanding of the word *closed* is a bit ambiguous, so what does it really mean for a vector space to be closed?

If I remove the word vector space, and instead use the word **set**, and ask what does it mean for a **set** to be closed, wouldn't that be more accurate to ask?

Then what is the difference between an **open set** and a **closed set**?

Could I also remove the terms; finite vector addition and scalar multiplication in the definition? Because where is subtraction and division? Would'nt leaving out those - if the set is in $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ be totally wrong?

Comment: With regards to the last part of your question, the statement: "a vector space V is a set that is closed under finite vector addition and scalar multiplication." is not the definition of a vector space, nor does Mathworld claim it is, if you read a bit further you will find the definition of a vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $S$ is closed under an operation $*$ if $a*b \in S$ whenever $a,b \in S$. This concept has nothing to do with the concept of a closed set in a topological space. When you say 'closed under' some operation the word 'under' is very important.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first interpretation, but then I mixed it up a bit. Aha, so you mean by closed that if $c=a*b$ then then $c$ is a member of the set $S$?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you’re getting confused with topology notions.

**To be closed under finite vector addition** means that if you add a finite number of vectors of a vector space $V$, you get an element (a vector) of $V$.

This is a totally different notion to **an open set** or **closed set** in topology.

Comment: Could you not add an **infinite** number of vectors in a vector space? or is that just related to set theory? But you mean closed is related to finiteness of operations done?

Comment: Adding **an infinite** number of vectors is’t always possible. For example $\mathbb R$ is a vector space. What would be the meaning of adding an infinite number of times the vector $1$? You need to endow the space with something like a norm and define convergence to be able to define infinite addition of vectors. So yes closed here is related to finiteness of operations.